# Update UILabel, UIbutton to second view controller imported from first view controller

Tags: ios, uilabel, viewcontroller

I am using tab bar navigation/I am a newbie.

I have ViewController1 which has all the IBOutlet UILabel, UIButton AND also some IBAction functions. I would like to pass all of these data to ViewController2.

this is what i try:
I noticed that in ViewController2 after I use: #import "Viewcontroller1.h" -- all these functions/outlets are available on the Main.storyboard. I started to connect these outlets to ViewController2 on Main.storyboard and they seem to work on the first load. HOWEVER, when I interact with the Viewcontroller1 and changing the UILabels, these will not get updated on the Viewcontroller2. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Regards,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

You have to define different IBOutlets and IBActions for each view controller in its respective .h file and implement it in its respective .m file.

Suppose you have two view controllers with a button named "Back" on each at exact same location and with exact same functionality. Then you'll have to define your IBOutlet and IBAction in the following way:

```
@interface ViewController1

@property(nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UIButton *backButton;

-(IBAction)on_back:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewController1

-(IBAction)on_back:(id)sender
{
  //your code for doing back action...
} 
@end

//similarly as above you'll have to write once 
//more in @interface and @implementation of ViewController2. 
//Once done, you can bind the respective IBOutlets and IBAction 
//from Storyboard or XIB/Nib file.
```